# Ruby on Rails RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

I am creating a webpage for events; the events section works, but I am getting an error that Ruby can't find a path from the front page of the website which queries the database for events.
The name shows up correctly, but when you click the link it refreshes to the same page with the error below:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/new/script.js"):
  actionpack (4.0.2)
```

These are my routes

```
     Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
    new_page GET    /new/page(.:format)         new#page
        root GET    /                           events#index
  front_page GET    /front/page(.:format)       front#page
      events GET    /events(.:format)           events#index
            POST    /events(.:format)           events#create  
   new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)       events#new
  edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)  events#edit
       event GET    /events/:id(.:format)       events#show
           PATCH    /events/:id(.:format)       events#update
             PUT    /events/:id(.:format)       events#update
          DELETE    /events/:id(.:format)       events#destroy
```

Comment: What is the exact location of the file script.js?

Comment: I used control find through the html page and I think it was just a false lead. I have been looking through articles on routing in ruby and is external redirects the way I need to go to get these two pages linked? For more information, I have events stored on a controller, and the front page on another controller. Events are being rendered through ajax. Thanks for your help

Comment: You may need to provide more information. Do you have a file called script.js that you are trying to access, eg in public? in that case it might simply be a matter of making sure you are using the right path eg /script.js instead of script.js? It looks like you might be in /new and your link to script.js is then ending up at /new/script.js

Comment: After looking online for some more information. I believe I just have to combine the two controllers into 1 so that the pathing will be fixed. Nothing online is leading me to believe that what I was trying to do was possible. Thanks for everyone's help!